# ECDSA Transaction Signature Values (V-R-S) -- Interpreting and presenting it to layman users

Tags: web3js, quorum, ecdsa

In Quorum + Web3, I used getTransaction and it returned me the necessary details and also V-R-S. Understand that VRS is part of the ECDSA signature.

There is a need to interpret and present these seemingly random hashes (I know they are not) to users to conclusively persuade them that this transaction is indeed performed by some party.

How would one decipher and explain ECDSA VRS to layman?

Comment: Why do you need to explain exactly how ECDSA signatures work to a layman? You should simply view it as a black box: if the verification algorithm accepts the given v,r,s then the signature is valid.

Comment: Some of the links here might help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/any-understandable-cryptography-book-article-lecture-to-introduce-to-signatures, but cryptography is a very technical area if you want to know the details behind.