# Any understandable cryptography book/article/lecture to introduce to signatures, hashes, ECDSA etc..?

Tags: blockchain, security, cryptography, ecdsa

It's a long time I'm searching for **cryptography lectures related to ethereum inside mechanisms**, and everything I found has a high mathematical level. I'm an engineer, not a mathematics, so any article or lecture recommended with an acceptable mathematical level?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi there. This question would be better suited to the Cryptography SE site as the technologies you mention aren't specific to Ethereum (and you'll likely get better, focused answers there). https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's true, but the question is about ethereum-only crypto, so that's why (i guess) he/she made the question here.

Comment: There is a series of blog post by Andrea Corbellini that is very good introduction with examples http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nice to see those questions, this demonstrates that people are interested in really learning how all this world works!

**I asked a few months ago to one of my college professors for the same** thing and he gave me this two titles:

- [**Applied cryptography. Alfred J. Menezes**](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/). It's a really nice title, **the chapters are free**, so download them one by one. The **mathematical language isn't on a very high-level**, an engineer like you or me can understand that. It **contains all of the basic concepts in order to understand how all of the things you asked for work**.
  It's a very nice book and **I highly recommend it**.

On the ECDSA side we have another Menezes book:

- [**Guide to elliptic curve cryptography. Alfred J. Menezes**](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.394.3037&rep=rep1&type=pdf). **A very well written introduction from RSA to ECDSA** algorithms also with a **very understandable mathematical language**.
  **I recommend you to read this the second. You'll understand it better with the first book's concepts learned.**

Hope it helps mate!
Enjoy the lectures!

Comment: I have a problem in verifying ECDSA signature when evrything semms ok. The question is here: [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert?noredirect=1#comment64505_54482)
Thank you very much for any comment.