# "UPDATED : " "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testrpc, payments, state-channels

I tested signature verification of the code presented [HERE](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/) as follows:

running `testRPC` :

```
root@ubuntu:/home/s# testrpc
EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0xa1fe30d3b82fd7c563b6fc9c44f3990bfcef3ed4
(1) 0xfadc848eea30a47a19ec8a62a42471de3e073b89
(2) 0x162e8acc48158f4e8961865f09f8d029d625161f
(3) 0x8f132b6c06b8a93ebc8689371c44fc8271ac9d73
(4) 0x4741548cb9a157522b353e94b9393ec537b1e352
(5) 0x6f786e92be3b0da9142f657a391bf7f91ae81910
(6) 0x3e90f71ea98ea71957f0cc9a1a5c4e0ad530a381
(7) 0xb3032b6bad1406fd6041839c4c9a0e544d3bd9a5
(8) 0x10f4925ac27d37df3ca1e8a4df37d3a94645a1a3
(9) 0x63021d2642b7f7581b963408436f69a6329195a8

Private Keys
==================
(0) f9059a43ab6d30687a95a5dcd2551b02f98a6abc557cacf17fb5a7586c30fc9e
(1) b74d7dad53e04db199f06f57f4e53e4bb0914d9d5118d367b6f7a39998bb45b7
(2) 837d2cb30033f7c218d6cd6fd4f7703f950495dae89c797e7dd01c6a469ed64c
(3) f7c1d7df52b765609315127f664363fea5df108bf414788e6eb4905005638b5e
(4) ec4b55a3ae654a5c2aeeeeb068c47c84808065a4a466148844763e0bdf7e87cf
(5) d7e75efcb275f2496790c86b9a5951ab86a9361d0e55604f9409cd9a6844b595
(6) adee6af8313963b68ce440d4ade36e7e1163d2bb9dd351152d73c6aee1b5ae95
(7) 6f3b9662e341aaae1131522c691834e0eb4a8a7987b8c39f412334ea4fc8050d
(8) d48189838281fd47802fe755767531433af116428379fdabadcf92779a6e157c
(9) acde15308f46d5f96ad229eef0a8b6b20e864e05cbf7063e83249cd1b6080425

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      other shell crater issue merit system age kitchen south mother lecture embrace
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545
```

And I chose the following addresses as `signer / sender` and `recipient` :

```
sender address = 0xa1fe30d3b82fd7c563b6fc9c44f3990bfcef3ed4
recipient address = 0xfadc848eea30a47a19ec8a62a42471de3e073b89
```

Deploying contract:

```
> const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
undefined
> 
> thisContract.deploy({  
... 
...         data: bytecode,
... 
...         arguments: [ "0xfadc848eea30a47a19ec8a62a42471de3e073b89", 2592000]
... 
...     }).send({
... 
...        from: "0xa1fe30d3b82fd7c563b6fc9c44f3990bfcef3ed4",
... 
...        gas: 5000000 ,
... 
...        gasPrice: '3000000000',
... 
...        value: 5000 
... 
...     },
... 
...     function(error, transactionHash) {
... 
...         console.log(error);
... 
...         console.log(transactionHash);
... 
...         console.log('function exec');
... 
...     }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
... 
...     console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
... 
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> null
0xee77c9011a4fb4d18cdf6804007ddc6b2b05828c7b8cac28f784f7b26c0021ef
function exec
Contract Instance:0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5
```

Getting `contract balance` :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5').then(console.log) // contract
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 5000
```

Here is JavaScript signing file (Note: I run this code after running testRPC and because of receiving some errors I had to modify some parts of code(I mentioned list of modifications at top of the code (Please see: `Modifications are as follows:`))):

```
// Modifications are as follows:
// ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3 -> ethereumjs.soliditySHA3
// web3.personal.sign -> web3.eth.sign
// web3.eth.defaultAccount -> "<signer address>" This address is changed depending on addresses generated by testRPC
// ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3 -> ethereumjs.soliditySHA3
// ethereumjs.Util.fromRpcSig -> ethJsUtil.fromRpcSig
// ethereumjs.Util.ecrecover -> ethJsUtil.ecrecover
// ethereumjs.Util.pubToAddress -> ethJsUtil.pubToAddress
//ethereumjs.Util.stripHexPrefix -> ethJsUtil.stripHexPrefix

Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var ethereumjs = require('ethereumjs-abi') //ethereumjs->ethjsabi
var ethJsUtil = require('ethereumjs-util') //ethJsUtil->ethjsutil

function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
  return ethereumjs.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
}

function signMessage(message, callback) {

    return sig = web3.eth.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"),
    "<signer address: This address is changed depending on addresses generated by testRPC>").
    then(console.log);

//console.log("signature= ", sig);

}


function signPayment(contractAddress, amount, callback) {

    var message = constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount);

    sig = signMessage(message, callback);

    //console.log("Signature= ", sig);
}

//

function prefixed(hash) {
  return ethereumjs.soliditySHA3(
    ["string", "bytes32"],
    ["\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash]
  );
}

function recoverSigner(message, signature) {
  //var split = ethereumjs.Util.fromRpcSig(signature);  

  var split = res = ethJsUtil.fromRpcSig(signature);

  var publicKey = ethJsUtil.ecrecover(message, split.v, split.r, split.s);
  var signer = ethJsUtil.pubToAddress(publicKey).toString("hex");
  return signer;
}

function isValidSignature(contractAddress, amount, signature, expectedSigner) {

  var message = prefixed(constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount));

  var signer = recoverSigner(message, signature);

  console.log("Signer Address= ", signer);

  return signer.toLowerCase() ==
    ethJsUtil.stripHexPrefix(expectedSigner).toLowerCase();
}

signPayment('<contract address>', 50, function(err, something) {});
//signature= 

//result = isValidSignature('<contract address>', 50,
//"<signature>", "<signer address>");

//console.log("Signature Verification Result= ", result);
```

Signing :

After inserting the values of signer address and contract address in above code, I run it : `node filename.js` and I get the signature.

```
signPayment('0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5', 50, function(err, something) {}); 
    //signature= 0xb6dec803b061504e22bccccffdfe26980ddaa33d650268361bec5ef4bd4a863f6ff2ee7d524f63cd82ef5634a063cd5e21f164c2ab1a6c952131308d6f46fb1200
```

This signature using `JavaScript` is verified however apparently by `Solidity` code it is not verified:

```
result = isValidSignature('0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5', 50,  "0xb6dec803b061504e22bccccffdfe26980ddaa33d650268361bec5ef4bd4a863f6ff2ee7d524f63cd82ef5634a063cd5e21f164c2ab1a6c952131308d6f46fb1200", "0xa1fe30d3b82fd7c563b6fc9c44f3990bfcef3ed4");
console.log("Signature Verification Result= ", result);
//result = true (Note that this verification is done using JavaScript and ethereumjs and not by Solidity that is my  problem)
```

Call `function close` to transfer `ether` and verifying signature and destroy `contract`

```
> var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5');
undefined
> 
> contractInstance.options.address;
'0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5'
> 
> 
> contractInstance.methods.close(50, "0xb6dec803b061504e22bccccffdfe26980ddaa33d650268361bec5ef4bd4a863f6ff2ee7d524f63cd82ef5634a063cd5e21f164c2ab1a6c952131308d6f46fb1200").send({ from: '0xfadc848eea30a47a19ec8a62a42471de3e073b89' }, function(error, result) {
... 
...     console.log(error);
... 
...     console.log(result)
... 
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: undefined,
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/s/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
    at /home/s/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/s/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:77:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/s/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/s/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/s/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/s/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:440:23)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
undefined
```

**Error:**

> ***error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert***

And here is `testrpc` message :

```
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0x2dbc6d601e48f6cab5327f162ff415d4e0b11264685a7ceed90de8d77adc2d8a
  Gas usage: 31867
  Block Number: 12
  Block Time: Tue Jul 17 2018 13:56:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)
  Runtime Error: revert
```

And when I get `contract balance` it's still `5000` :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xa6D8893aAF5121AEfb496aB305e0DA42F71aAaa5').then(console.log) // contract 
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 5000
```

**Note 1:**

*When I remove `signature` from `function close` as follows, transferring `ether` is done, since when I get `contract balance` it becomes `zero`. However, with signature I receive the above error message.*

```
function close(uint256 amount) public {

        recipient.transfer(amount);
        selfdestruct(sender);
    }
```

**Note 2:**

Meanwhile I added a new function as follow to get value of `message` in :

```
bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, amount)));
```

by which I can get value of `recoverSigner(message, signature)` :

So I defined following function and deployed contract again :

```
function returnMsg(uint256 amount) public

    returns (bytes32)

    {
        bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, amount)));
        return message;
    }
```

However, I could not get value of `message` and I only received transaction receipt as follows:

```
    > contractInstance.methods.returnMsg(50).send({ from: '0x39969849de82f978e9f356ffa5516f8d25f44ddc' }, function(error, result) {
    ... 
    ...     console.log(error);
    ... 
    ...     console.log(result)
    ... 
    ... });
    Promise {
      <pending>,
      domain: 
       Domain {
         domain: null,
         _events: 
          { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
            newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
            error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
         _eventsCount: 3,
         _maxListeners: undefined,
         members: [] },
      _events: undefined,
      emit: [Function: emit],
      on: [Function: on],
      once: [Function: once],
      off: [Function: removeListener],
      listeners: [Function: listeners],
      addListener: [Function: on],
      removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
      removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
    > null
    0xb6dc221924f4ce6fffe184297b68649cf5ec2ab64c8413a20c9f0d1d8233f04c

    // And when I get transaction status "contract address is "null" : "

    > var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xb6dc221924f4ce6fffe184297b68649cf5ec2ab64c8413a20c9f0d1d8233f04c').then(console.log);
undefined
> { transactionHash: '0xb6dc221924f4ce6fffe184297b68649cf5ec2ab64c8413a20c9f0d1d8233f04c',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0xf65f637eba42b5fb29dfa051ea8d3c1bc876395210fe635b3dd7333a8a7f7307',
  blockNumber: 2,
  gasUsed: 22861,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 22861,
  contractAddress: null,
  logs: [],
  status: true }
```

**Important Note:** *Please note that verifying signature using `JavaScript` is verified however apparently by `Solidity` code it is not verified and I think because of this transaction is reverted, Since as I mentioned in my question, without signature verification `ether` is transferred and contract is destroyed successfully.*

Comment: Did the call to `close()` actually succeed? Check the `status` field in the transaction receipt. My guess is that `close` failed, so presumably the signature is wrong in some way. (An simple way to verify would be to remove the `require` in `close()` that checks the signature and see if that makes the transaction work.)

Comment: @smarx Thank you, Yes, in my opinion `function isValidSignature(uint256 amount, bytes signature)` returns `false`. However, I checked signature verification by `JavaScript` code (`function isValidSignature(contractAddress, amount, signature, expectedSigner)`) and it returns `true`. As screen shot shows, I called `close` by the same `amount` and the same `signature`. Meanwhile, do not we need to insert `contract address` as input parameter in `function close`?(like JavaScript code?)I'll check it again tomorrow and share the result here. (I call `close` without `require`) I hope it works. Thanks

Comment: In the future, please share text, not screenshots. It's much harder to read the screenshots and impossible to copy/paste. (And of course blind users have no way of knowing what's in there.) It looks like in the screenshot where you're calling `close()`, your contract address is wrong. (You've used the `recipient`'s address instead of the contract's.)

Comment: @smarx Thanks. OK, Sure, I share text. Yes, I inserted `recipient address` as  `from`. because I thought the `msg.sender` must be `recipient address`. I'm wrong ? Thanks

Comment: `from` when sending the transaction is correct. It's the contract address that's wrong: `new web3.eth.Contract(abi, <wrong address here>`.

Comment: @smarx Yes, You're right ... it must be `0x2e8c7b208503759e2CF4a9EDA8Ae52e816dc3d38` ... Sorry ... I test it again. Thank you very much and I hope tomorrow I get `true`. Thanks

Comment: @smarx Hi, I tested contract again and this time I receive : `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`. I shared what I did in text and updated my question. Thank you

Comment: @smarx I added a new note **(Note 2)** to my question about how to get `signer address`. Thank you

Comment: @smarx Sorry, concerning new added function : `returnMsg` I used : `var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xb6dc221924f4ce6fffe184297b68649cf5ec2ab64c8413a20c9f0d1d8233f04c').then(console.log);`  to get `tx status` and `contractAddress: null` is it normal ? and where is value of `message` that is returned ? Thanks

Comment: Regarding your `returnMsg()` function, transactions don't have return values. You need to `call` the function rather than send a transaction. If you make the function a `view` function, this will just happen automatically.

Comment: @smarx Thank you, my purpose is to get the output of `return recoverSigner(message, signature)` to be sure which `value / address` is returned. Do you think it is possible ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just make it a `view` function.

Comment: @smarx There is a `Ethereum: Signing and Validating` code HERE : [link](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3) that is mentioned : **"NOTE: THIS WILL NOT WORK ON TESTRPC"** without mentioning the reason.

Comment: Are you using testrpc to sign? What's your web3 provider? (This would typically be MetaMask.)

Comment: @smarx Yes, first I run testrpc (as I mention in the question) and then choose two generated addresses by testrpc as sender/signer and recipient. I use the same addresses for deploying contract and calling function `close`. The signature is verified by JS code, however, in Solidity apparently does not work. So, does it mean that I cannot use `testrpc` for signing payment ? Btw I do not use MetaMast. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the line that starts `web3 = new Web3(...)`? I want to know what's in there. If you're connecting directly to testrpc, then I'm a bit confused, because I didn't think testrpc implemented `web3.personal.sign` at all. Did you modify the code from the blog post? If so, please just share your whole  code.

Comment: Testrpc is fine, but you may need to use MetaMask (as you would in a real-world implementation) to connect to it. Some tweaks to the code could probably make a direct connection to testrpc work, but it's probably not worth doing (since you would never use that in a real implementation).

Comment: @smarx Yes, since I was receiving some error, I modified a little the JS code (ex. in case of `web3.personal.sign`). At the moment, I do not have access to the code, but tomorrow morning I share the entire JS code with all modifications. I think the problem is going to be solved ! Thanks

Comment: @smarx I shared JS code with all modification in question. Please see: "_Here is JavaScript signing file..._". If you need any other information please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that you're connecting directly to `testrpc`, which signs messages differently. As I said, it's possible to adapt the code to work, but there's no real point. (You'd just have to throw away those changes when you deployed the code for real.) You also appear to be using node.js, but it makes little sense to run this code there. If you really want to make this code run for some reason, modify the signatures you get to end in `1b` or `1c`. You should also really switch to `ganache-cli`. (`testrpc` is deprecated and stale.)

Comment: @smarx and concerning `web3` I use `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` in Javascript file. Thanks

Comment: @smarx Thank you, So what is the best way to run your `JavaScript` code **without any modification** ? (instead of using `node filename.js` ?) to generate signature? And also in this case is it not easier to use `Ropsten` instead of `ganache-cli` ? Thanks

Comment: In the browser, with MetaMask. `ganache-cli` is just fine (and faster than Ropsten). MetaMask can be pointed at localhost:8545.

Comment: @smarx Thank you, and with browser, do I need to add `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` and `require('ethereumjs-abi')` and `require('ethereumjs-util')` at top of the code in Console of browser ? And also before running JS code in browser, do I need to connect to ex. `Ropsten` by MetaMask ? Thanks

Comment: Those libraries have instructions for how to include them in script tags. Any tutorial on MetaMask will tell you how to use it.

Comment: @smarx concerning `ganache-cli` it seems that I need to modify JavaScript code (as I did) and it may lead to generate signature differently.

Comment: @smarx I appreciate if you could share a link which explains how to add those library in browser Console to generate signature. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80342/discussion-on-question-by-sas-updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transa).

Answer (score 0):

You should test your signature checking function alone by means of specific test. Did it works? Integrate it only when you are sure it works.