# Is the signature generated by "web3.personal.sign" different with "web3.eth.sign"?

Tags: web3js, signature, ecdsa

Are `web3.personal.sign` and `web3.eth.sign` difference in **value of generate signature** ? Or both of them generate an equal output ?

I could test `web3.eth.sign` using `testRPC`, however `web3.personal.sign` with `testRPC` gives error and I could not compare the output of both method with the same input.

Comment: In general, even signing the same message twice with the same ECDSA function will give different results, since the `k` value is chosen randomly each time

Comment: @Tjaden Hess Thank you, My main purpose is to run successfully `JavaScript` code presented here: [link](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/) when i run it using `node` i receive some errors. Do you know what is the best way of running this `JS` code ? Do i need to create an `html` file and run it with `browser` ? or it's better to create a `JS` file and run it using `node filename.js` ? I describe the main question here: [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think I had similar problem. I couldn't get correct address from ecrecover after message was signed with personal.sign, but it works fine after it was sign with eth.sign. 
Then I found this on web3 docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#sign

> "Signs data using a specific account. This data is before UTF-8 HEX
>   decoded and enveloped as follows: "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" +
>   message.length + message."

After I added "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" and message length to signed message,  from which I want to recover address, it finally return correct address.