# How to be sure "ethereumjs" is installed?

Tags: testrpc, javascript, ethereumjs, ganache, browsers

I installed `ethereumjs` library using following command:

```
npm i ethereumjs-testrpc
```

And here is the output:

[image]

And then I tried to run an `html` example which uses `ethereumjs-vm`. The example is here :
https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/blob/master/examples/vm.html

However, when I open this `html` file, there is an error message :

> ***ethereumjs is not defined.***

Here is screen shot:

[image]

Does it mean that I need to modigy following directory in the `html` file ?

```
<script src="../dist/ethereumjs-vm/ethereumjs-vm-2.3.1.js"></script>
```

**Note:**  My **main purpose** is to run successfully `JavaScript` code presented [HERE](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/) . When I run it using `node` I receive some errors. What is the best way of running this `JavaScript` code? Do I need to create an `html` file and run it with `browser`? or it's better to create a `JavaScript` file and run it using `node filename.js` ? The problem with running this code that is for signature verification is explained in details [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert) . Eventually, I had to change some part of `JavaScript` code (I precised which parts have been changed in my question [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert) ). However, eventually, when I call the function of `Solidity` contract (i.e. `function close`) to verify `signature`, the transaction is **reverted** as I mentioned the details of error [HERE.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert)

Comment: You can install it globally, via `npm install ethereumjs-testrpc -g`. However, this is generally not recommended. The correct way is to ensure that you execute your client code from the same path in which you have installed the `npm` package locally.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you, I installed it globally, however i receive the same error. Btw, when i sreach `ethereumjs-vm` in my computer, no result. My main purpose is to run successfully JavaScript code presented here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/ when i run it using `node` i receive some errors. Do you know what is the best way of running this JS code ? Do i need to create an `html` file and run it with browser? or it's better to create a `JS` file and run it using `node filename.js` ? Thanks

Comment: There's tons of stuff in this link. If you want me (or anyone else for that matter) to refer to your question, then synthesize the relevant part and post it here.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you, I modified my question. If there is something still unclear please let me know. Thanks